# Limit points of $z^n$ ($z\in\mathbb{C}$)?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, limits-without-lhopital

The exercise is to find the limit points of $z^n$ where $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is a complex number?

However, if $z=-1$ we have the limit points $1$ and $-1$, for $z=1$ we have the limit point $1$ and for $z=2$ we have no limit point. So how can you determine the limit points of $z^n$ in general?

Comment: Since $|z^n| = |z|^n$, if $|z| < 1$ we have $\lim_{n \to \infty} |z^n| = 0$, so $0$ is the only limit point. What happens if $|z| > 1$? This leaves only the (more subtle) case $|z| = 1$, whose answer, as you've already observed, depends on $z$.

Comment: Presuming that you mean the sets $\{ z^n \}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ for different $z$, there are four cases that you should consider:  (1) $|z| < 1$, (2) $|z| > 1$, (3) $z = \mathrm{e}^{i\pi\theta}$ with $\theta \in \mathbb{Q}$, and (4) $z = \mathrm{e}^{i\pi\theta}$ with $\theta\not \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: It's about [geometric progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression).

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can determine the limit points easily if $|z|\neq1$ (you have two cases to consider). Now consider what happens when $|z|=1$, which is equivalent to $z=e^{\pi i\theta}$. The cases depend on the rationality of $\theta$, so how does it affect the limit points?

Comment: Ok, so I take $z^n = e^{i\phi n} = |z|^n (\cos(n\phi) + i\sin(n\phi))$. If $|z| < 1$ then this becomes $0$ and the limit point is $0$, but if $|z|>1$ then $|z|^n$ become arbitrary large and there is no limit point. So far correct?

Comment: But how do deal with $|z|=1$?

Comment: @Simon: so far so good; to ease your troubles, you don’t need to expand $e^{i\theta}$. Think of how it travels around the circle...does it repeat certain points? If so, how often? If not, then...?

Comment: Ok, so for $|z|=1$ I get $|\cos(n\phi) + i\cos(n\phi) -\cos(\omega) - i\sin(\omega)|$. This is zero if $n\phi = \omega$. Does this mean, that the limit points are $e^{i\omega}$ with $\omega$ that are multiples of $\phi$?

Comment: @SimonMueller: $e^{i\pi\theta\cdot n}$ is a repeating sequence if $\theta$ is rational (why?). If $\theta$ is irrational, it never repeats.

Comment: Because then I can write $\theta$ as $\theta = a/b$ and so for $n=b$ the $n$ and $b$ cancel out. So do you mean, that for $|z|=1$ the limit points are all rational $\theta$? I still do not quite understand how get to the actual limit points from here?

Comment: @SimonMueller: Suppose $\theta=p/q$ with $(p,q)=1$. Then the limit points will be precisely the $0,1,\ldots,q-1$ points on the unit circle. If $\theta$ is irrational, then the limit points turn out to be the entire unit circle.